# Why is Android Studio asking me to exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'?

Tags: android, android-library

I'm running Studio 1.1.0 and I recently added Joda-Time-2.7.jar. After I tried to run the project I got the error:

> Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/LICENSE.txt
>
> File 1: /libs/twitter4j-core-4.0.2.jar
>
> File 2: /libs/twitter4j-core-4.0.2.jar

```
Error:duplicate files during packaging of APK /build/outputs/apk/app-debug-unaligned.apk
Path in archive: META-INF/LICENSE.txt
Origin 1: /libs/twitter4j-core-4.0.2.jar
Origin 2: /.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/joda-time/joda-time/2.7/55997..842195/joda-time-2.7.jar
```

I can add this and it will run fine:

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
}
```

Why am I getting this error after adding Joda-Time? Why are Twitter4j and Joda-Time conflicting?

Is excluding 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt' a good solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Duplicate files are not allowed when packaging an APK (unless they need to be merged, but that's another story). In your case both jars contain `META-INF/LICENSE.txt` file, so Gradle complains about that.

`exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'` tells Gradle to exclude this file from packaging process. Since this is just a text with the license - its totally fine. License doesn't have to be included into final APK.